# how to trigger page refresh when using browser back and forward buttons in angular

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I m using angular. Whenever I append parameters in the URL like `/#/?param1=asd&param2=123`
 `/#/?param1=asd&param2=123&param3=1233` the tab doesnt refresh. It just fires a callback

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

How do I force my web app to refresh when there is a change in the URL and not just state change?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe yo need to set

```
$window.location.href
```

This reload the page after changing the URL.
[use of $location in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)